# main title in plot consisting of pictures is out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I ma trying to make plot consisting of 6 images, each with it's own title and above all have main title for whole plot. When I try to create it it is visible in inline graphics, but when saved as png it is off the plot. I have tried making figure vertically bigger, but it did not help

**Visible in line:**
[image: plot in line - very good]

**When saved to file** - it lacks main title:
[image: plot when saved to file - :(]

Data to test:

1) creating temporary photo to work with 0 in my real problem this are diffrent images

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Test_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], \
                               'y' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

#creating fake photo
plt.plot(Test_df['x'], Test_df['y'], "o")
plt.savefig('test.png')

#read as picture
tmp = cv2.imread('test.png')
```

2) creating final plot

```
#creating desired plot
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(7.5,5))

# add main title
f.text(0, 1, 'main title', 
         fontsize=15, fontweight='black', color = '#333F4B')

for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,4):
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].imshow(tmp)
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].set_axis_off()
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].axis("tight")  # gets rid of white border
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].axis("image") # square up the image instead of filling the "figure" space
        title = str(i + j)
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].set_title(title, fontsize = 8, color = '#333F4B')
        axarr[i - 1, j - 1].set_facecolor('b')


plt.tight_layout()         

plt.savefig('result.png')
```

EDIT

It worked ok, when used `subtitle` and removed `plt.tight_layout()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using it as a text right now, it somehow is getting clipped due to the `tight_layout` while saving. Your code will work fine if instead of `1` for the y-coordinate, you use something up to 0.97. To test that, try also `f.text(0, 0.97, 'main title', ....`

I would recommend to use the in-built function [`suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) for this task.

---

```
f.suptitle('main title', x=0, y=1, fontsize=15, 
           fontweight='black', color = '#333F4B') 
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]